# Java waitable object container

Tags: java

Are there existing frameworks implementing the following approach?

```
public class WaitableContainer<T> {
  private T object;
  public <T> peekAwait() {...} // returns object if object !=null or makes the caller thread sleep until object != null
  public actuate(T object) {
    this.object = object; // here all sleeping threads must awake and receive the new object
  }
}
```

Need some kind of an object wrapper which will make the caller thread alsep until an other thread will set the object.

Comment: I think BlockingQueue interface might be helpful (at least for the first method). I don't really get ehwat actuate is supposed to do

Comment: also you can try java Future

Comment: Look like it is work for `CyclicBarrier`

Comment: You design assume that some thread can skip object if they did not call `peekAwait` yet. Is this true? Are you ready to meet scenario when you `actuate` object and there is no one to peek it and it vanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

```
// container.actuate(o); becomes
future.complete(o);

// container.peekAwait(); becomes
future.get();
```

If you can't use Java 8, [FutureTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) is a decent choice for a workaround, but rather than explicitly setting it, you provide a Callable that returns the value you want to set.

```
final FutureTask<Object> lazyLoadedData = new FutureTask<>(() -> expensiveIO());

...

if (!lazyLoadedData.isDone()) {
    synchronized(lazyLoadedData) {
        if (!lazyLoadedData.isDone()) {
            // run() does the computation and sets the data
            // essentially, lazyLoadedData.set(expensiveIO())
            lazyLoadedData.run();
        }
    }
}
// Data is available
lazyLoadedData.get();
```

If you *plan* on having an ExecutorService do this, it already returns a Future;

```
final FutureTask<Object> future = executorService.submit(() -> expensiveIO());

// Now you just need to call get()
future.get();
```